Generic[T] classmethod implicit type retrieval in Python 3.12
I would like to use the new Python 3.12 generic type signature syntax to know the type of an about-to-be-instantiated class within the classmethod of that class.
For example, I would like to print the concrete type of T in this example:
class MyClass[T]:
    kind: type[T]

    ...

    @classmethod
    def make_class[T](cls) -> "MyClass[T]":
        print("I am type {T}!")
        return cls()

I've used the advice in the following StackOverflow question to do this for reifying the type within both __new__ and __init__ but I have yet to to figure out a clever way to do this in either a static or class method (ideally a class method).

Generic[T] base class - how to get type of T from within instance?

My goal is to have the following API:
>>> MyClass[int].make_class()
"I am type int!"

Or this API (which I don't think is syntactically possible yet):
>>> MyClass.make_class[int]()
"I am type int!"

Where in either case, the returned instance would have int bound to the class variable so I can use it later.
MyClass[int].make_class().kind is int == True

I am open to "hacks" (including heavy use of inspect).

If you read the source code of typing.py, you'll see that the type arguments for a Generic is stored as the __args__ attribute of the base class _BaseGenericAlias. Note that this is an undocumented implementation detail.
We then just need to patch its proxy attribute getter _BaseGenericAlias.__getattr__ to inject an additional keyword argument into the method call with a wrapper function when the method is decorated with a classmethod subclass that marks the function with a special attribute:
class TypeArgsClassMethod(classmethod):
    def __get__(self, obj, obj_type=None):
        method = super().__get__(obj, obj_type)
        method.__func__._inject_type_args = True
        return method

def __getattr__(self, name):
    if hasattr(obj := orig_getattr(self, name), '_inject_type_args'):
        @wraps(obj)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return obj(*args, __type_args__=self.__args__, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return obj

if 'orig_getattr' not in globals():
    orig_getattr = _BaseGenericAlias.__getattr__
    _BaseGenericAlias.__getattr__ = __getattr__

so that:
class MyClass[T]:
    kind: type[T]

    @TypeArgsClassMethod
    def make_class(cls, __type_args__) -> "MyClass[T]":
        print(__type_args__)
        return cls()

MyClass[int].make_class()

outputs:
(<class 'int'>,)

Demo here
Alternatively, you can rebind the custom class method to the Generic type, so that the first argument of the class method would become the Generic type. The built-in types.MethodType does not allow __self__ to be updated for a rebind so you would have to define a Python-equivalent version:
from functools import update_wrapper
from typing import _BaseGenericAlias

class MethodType:
    def __init__(self, func, obj):
        self.__func__ = func
        self.__self__ = obj

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        func = self.__func__
        obj = self.__self__
        return func(obj, *args, **kwargs)

class GenericClassMethod:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        update_wrapper(self, f)

    def __get__(self, obj, cls=None):
        if cls is None:
            cls = type(obj)
        method = MethodType(self.f, cls)
        method._generic_classmethod = True
        return method

def __getattr__(self, name):
    if hasattr(obj := orig_getattr(self, name), '_generic_classmethod'):
        obj.__self__ = self
    return obj

if 'orig_getattr' not in globals():
    orig_getattr = _BaseGenericAlias.__getattr__
    _BaseGenericAlias.__getattr__ = __getattr__

so that you can access its __args__ attribute for the type arguments, and its __origin__ attribute for the original class:
class MyClass[T]:
    kind: type[T]

    @GenericClassMethod
    def make_class(cls) -> "MyClass[T]":
        print(cls)
        print(cls.__origin__)
        print(cls.__args__)

MyClass[int].make_class()

This outputs:
__main__.MyClass[int]
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
(<class 'int'>,)

Demo here
Finally, an even more seamless approach that would achieve the behavior of substiting the type variable T with the actual argument as suggested in your question would be to map the type variables the in cell content of the class method's function closure to the corresponding type arguments.
This approach has the benefit of avoiding any alteration to the class method's usage (with no injection of an argument and no change to the nature of the cls argument) so you can avoid having to define a custom classmethod descriptor. To identify a class method you can use the isclassmethod function offered in this answer:
from typing import _BaseGenericAlias
from types import FunctionType, CellType
from collections.abc import Hashable
from operator import attrgetter

def __getattr__(self, name):
    if (isclassmethod(obj := orig_getattr(self, name)) and
            (func := obj.__func__).__closure__):
        param_to_arg = dict(zip(self.__origin__.__parameters__, self.__args__))
        return FunctionType(
            func.__code__,
            func.__globals__,
            func.__name__,
            func.__defaults__,
            tuple(
                CellType(
                    param_to_arg.get(value, value)
                    if isinstance(value, Hashable) else value
                )
                for value in map(attrgetter('cell_contents'), func.__closure__)
            )
        ).__get__(obj.__self__)
    return obj

if 'orig_getattr' not in globals():
    orig_getattr = _BaseGenericAlias.__getattr__
    _BaseGenericAlias.__getattr__ = __getattr__

so that:
class MyClass[T]:
    @classmethod
    def make_class(cls):
        print(T)
    
MyClass[int].make_class()

outputs:
<class 'int'>

Demo here

This is going to break any code that tries to use classmethods with generic types and expects the standard behavior, though. Might want to add a marker or something for classes to opt into this behavior, so other classes aren't affected.

Good point. I"ve updated my answer accordingly then. Thanks.

I've updated my answer with what I think is a more seamless solution.

@blhsing fantastic! This is exactly what I was hoping for and I favor the second @GenericClassMethod approach. In demo'ing this out in a Jupyter notebook I notice that re-executing the code twice results in an exception so I might seek to modify my implementation to guard against that. Kudos!

@clintval You're welcome. Indeed if you re-execute the code you should guard against overwriting orig_getattr if _BaseGenericAlias.__getattr__ is already patched. I've updated my answer with such a guard then.

I've updated my answer with an even more seamless solution that actually achieves the behavior specified in the OP.

@blhsing I'm still reviewing but decided to run the code and am not finding that the guard for re-executing the code is working (if _BaseGenericAlias.__getattr__ is not __getattr__) as I am hitting a recursion error and TypeError: __getattr__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name' . In my library code which has other generic and non-generic classes with classmethods I hit TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable on line for value in map(attrgetter("cell_contents"), function.__closure__) too. I'll keep debugging but if it's an easy fix, I'd appreciate it!

@clintval Indeed I forgot to take into account that __closure__ can be None for a function without a closure. Added a check for it then. As for the issue with the re-execution guard, indeed I forgot that re-executing the code would assign to __getattr__ a new function object so it would not be the same as the old reference kept in _BaseGenericAlias.__getattr__. I've switched the guard to if 'orig_getattr' not in globals(): instead then.

the world of crutches
